# Sending mail failure in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sendmail

I trying to send Asynchronous mail using the folowing code :

```
 #region Method :: Send Email
        public static void vSendMail(string sEmailAddress, string sSubject = "", string sMsgBody = "", int nUserID = 1, Telerik.Reporting.ReportSource reportSource = null, List<string> ccUsersEmails = null)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"];
                string email = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Email"];


                sMsgBody = "";// PopulateBody("", "", url.Split('!')[0], sMsgBody);


                BaseClass _baseClass = new BaseClass();
                var FromAddress = new MailAddress(CommonTools.Decrypt(email.Split('!')[0], true, _baseClass.UserID), "Metal Art Work");
                var ToAddress = new MailAddress(sEmailAddress, sEmailAddress);
                string sFromPassword = CommonTools.Decrypt(email.Split('!')[1], true, _baseClass.UserID);
                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"],
                    Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]),
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    //UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromAddress.Address, sFromPassword)
                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage(FromAddress, ToAddress)
                {
                    Subject = sSubject,
                    Body = sMsgBody,
                    IsBodyHtml = true
                })
                {
                    //--Cc Emails--\\
                    if (ccUsersEmails != null)
                    {
                       //add  CC
                    }
                    //--Attachment--\\
                    if (reportSource != null)
                    {
                       // Add attach
                    }
                   // smtp.Send(message);
                    SendEmail(message, smtp, true);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                vAddToLog(ex, nUserID, ErrorCodes.SendMailError);
                throw new JOVALException(ex);
            }
        }
        private delegate void SendEmailDelegate(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m);
        private static void SendEmailResponse(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                SendEmailDelegate sd = (SendEmailDelegate)(ar.AsyncState);

                sd.EndInvoke(ar);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                vAddToLog(ex, 0, ErrorCodes.SendMailError);
            }
        }
        public static void SendEmail(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m, SmtpClient smtpClient, Boolean Async)
        {
            try
            {
            //   string userState = "Test";

                if (Async)
                {
                    SendEmailDelegate sd = new SendEmailDelegate(smtpClient.Send);
                    AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(SendEmailResponse);
                    sd.BeginInvoke(m, cb, sd);
                }
                else
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(m);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                vAddToLog(ex, 0, ErrorCodes.SendMailError);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

but  I face the following exception:

**Failure sending mail. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
    Object name: 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage**

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. Don't put variables in a `using()` block if you plan to use them later.

Comment: Thanks very much. it works fine